# Possible to "Root" Microsoft Surface?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-surface

With the release of a new tablet, I'm inclined to wonder how similar it is to other tablet devices, specifically those by Google and Apple. Is privilege escalation possible on a Surface? What I'm referring to is the equivalent process of Jailbreaking on iOS devices, and Rooting on Android devices. Or is the Surface more like a desktop OS, where privilege escalation is the simple matter of knowing the admin password?

Comment: Only time will tell. But then again, I'm more excited about rooting the other tablets (Kindle HD & Nexus 7) so I can get a cheap Windows RT device!

Comment: Wait so let me get this straight. On a Surface tablet you don't have admin permissions?

Comment: @mwong I don't think you have access to the hardware before Windows RT loads. See Secure Boot.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, no. In the future, possibly. Places you might want to keep your eye on:

1. [XDA Developers](http://www.xda-developers.com/tag/windows-8/)
2. [Hack N Mod](http://hacknmod.com/tag/microsoft-surface/)

Sources: first ten google results of the following queries

1. [root microsoft surface](https://www.google.com/search?oq=root%20microsoft%20surface&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=root%20microsoft%20surface)
2. [hack microsoft surface](https://www.google.com/search?oq=root%20microsoft%20surface&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=root%20microsoft%20surface#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=hack%20microsoft%20surface&oq=hack%20microsoft%20surface&gs_l=serp.3..0i30.77381.78019.0.78190.5.5.0.0.0.1.111.384.4j1.5.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.siYhP8cK5i0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=80ef5323c76d6b79&bpcl=35466521&biw=1920&bih=995)
3. [hack windows rt](https://www.google.com/search?oq=root%20microsoft%20surface&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=root%20microsoft%20surface#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=hack%20windows%20rt&oq=hack%20windows%20rt&gs_l=serp.3..0i8l3j0i8i30.81199.82783.1.82921.15.10.0.4.4.0.137.860.7j3.10.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.42TzCLHYoy8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=80ef5323c76d6b79&bpcl=35466521&biw=1920&bih=995)
4. [linux on microsoft surface](https://www.google.com/search?oq=root%20microsoft%20surface&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=root%20microsoft%20surface#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=linux%20on%20microsoft%20surface&oq=linux%20on%20microsoft%20surface&gs_l=serp.3..0i7j0i20j0i5l2.24343.24560.4.25131.3.3.0.0.0.0.77.218.3.3.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.W_EeXfzECLI&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=80ef5323c76d6b79&bpcl=35466521&biw=1920&bih=995)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Jailbreak tool for Windows RT 8.0](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2092158).

But none for 8.1 so far. It seems like the one developing a Jailbreak for RT 8.1 [stopped working on 8.1](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/26qz9b/windows_rt_81_jailbreak_progress_halted/) months ago and started working on Windows 10 instead now.

So I hope, there will be a Jailbreak for RT 8.1 soon.